# Search, Delete and Merge in dataframe in python

Tags: python

My master DataFrame is like below:-

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 | 1 | 10 |
| 2020-12-10 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-11-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2 | 50 |
| 2020-10-20 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-10-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-10-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-01-10 | 2 | 10 |

It contains 3 columns, date, id and value.

There is a child DataFrame with same structure as above and values can be as below :-

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 | 1 | 10 |
| 2020-12-10 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-12-20 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-12-30 | 2 | 10 |

Have to compare these two DataFrames, and merge this child DataFrame to master DataFrame, so the resultant DataFrame will look like:-

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 | 1 | 10 |
| 2020-12-10 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-12-20 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-12-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-11-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-11-01 | 2 | 50 |
| 2020-10-20 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-10-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-10-30 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 10 |
| 2020-01-10 | 2 | 10 |

Searching index for rows in master DataFrame can be either on Date or Id or can be a combination of Date and Id.

Note:- Date, Id and Value in above DataFrames are all in string

I haven't implemented the code yet, just need assistance on headstart, as I am fairly new to python.

Thanks

Comment: You should provide samples of both your DataFrames and your expected output.

Comment: As well as what code you have written in your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Have updated my problem statement. Thanks

Comment: How is this merging supposed to work? Some rows of the Master Data Frame and also some of the Expected Output Frame have identical values. Please reduce the Data Frames to a minimal example that explains your problem. I will be happy to take a look at it!